# BETWEEN exige argumentos na ordem crescente? Por quê?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte tabela fictícia.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM ALUNOS
WHERE IDADE BETWEEN 10 AND 15
```

Retorna os alunos A, C e D.

Agora, pq quando eu inverto a ordem no BETWEEN

```
SELECT * FROM ALUNOS
WHERE IDADE BETWEEN 15 AND 10
```

Não retorna nada?

Comment: porque o between pega sempre [maior] => [menor] como 15 > 10, ele invalida o beetween. pois não existe intervalo de 15 à 10.

Comment: Tudo bem que o comando possui como padrão pegar do menor - > maior. Agora, entre 10 e 15 eu tenho {10,11,12,13,14,15} e entre 15 e 10 eu tenho {15,14,13,12,11,10}.. o mesmo intervalo porém em outra ordem...Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: Obrigado pelo respostas. Dúvida esclarecida após um entendimento matemático. Obrigado

Comment: Enio, o problema é que é assim porque é assim. Não sei se tem uma resposta melhor que isso. Podia considerar ao contrário também, isso seria até uma mão na roda em certos casos, mas não é assim que funciona em SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, entendo que há alguma motivação lógica na pergunta. Se algo está entre 1 e 3, em princípio está entre 3 e 1.

O que não é verdade se for um comércio que abre das 22h até as 6h da manhã. Entre 6h e 22h ele estará fechado. Entre 22h e 6h estará aberto. Em outras palavras, conceitos muitas vezes são relativizados.

Isto posto, vamos responder à pergunta:

É assim, pois quem definiu a função quis assim. A interpretação do(s) criador(es) da função é que os dados estarão em ordem crescente. Não se trata deles terem um raciocínio melhor do que o seu e nem o inverso disso. Se você criar uma linguagem e definir que o seu BETWEEN vai funcionar independente de ordem de parâmetro, eu acredito que vá estar certo também.

De qualquer forma, se você precisar saber independente de ordem, basta fazer isto:

```
a BETWEEN( b, c ) OR a BETWEEN( c, b )
```

Pode não ser tão elegante quanto chamar uma função só, mas em compensação, sabendo da "limitação" da função, ela pode ser útil em algum momento em que a ordem for importante.

Exagerando: eu poderia fazer uma terceira linguagem com um BETWEEN que desse resultado invertido se os parâmetros estivessem invertidos, seria perfeito no caso do exemplo que eu dei de horário de funcionamento. `10 BETWEEN( 5, 15 ) => true` e `20 BETWEEN ( 15, 5 ) => true` (como se invertendo os parâmetros, valesse a "volta" por fora da numeração, começando de 15 e indo até o infinito positivo, e do infinito negativo terminando em 5)

No fim, o que vale é a [documentação](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174081(v=sql.110).aspx). E quando está atualizada ;)

Comment: Salvou o dia. Muito Obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 5):

Porque é **sempre** do **menor** (10) para o **maior** (15).

`BETWEEN begin_expression AND end_expression`

https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174081(v=sql.110).aspx

### Exemplo

```
SELECT [Product ID], [Product Name] FROM Products WHERE [Units In Stock] BETWEEN '0' AND '35'
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu intervalo está **incorreto**.

Não existe o intervalo de 15 até o 10.

`BETWEEN` é usado para selecionar valores num intervalo.

Se o seu objetivo é selecionar registros que não está nesse intervalo deve usar `NOT BETWEEN` assim ele trará todos os registos que **NÃO** estão no seu intervalo (lembrando que o intervalo inicial deve ser menor que o intervalo final).

Comment: Tudo bem que o comando possui como padrão pegar do menor - > maior. Agora, entre 10 e 15 eu tenho {10,11,12,13,14,15} e entre 15 e 10 eu tenho {15,14,13,12,11,10}.. o mesmo intervalo porém em outra ordem...Obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 1):

É apenas um padrão.

Mas acredito que assim foi padronizado porque o inverso daria o mesmo resultado.

Seria redundante e geraria custos com processos ao implementar no compilador qual parâmetro é maior ou menor.

Por mais simples e imperceptível que seja o ganho em performance, poupar 00000000000000.1s é uma boa economia.